# How to call angular animation enter after leave finish

Tags: angular, animation

I am using this code to animate list of divs

```
trigger('listOfDivsInOut', [
      transition('* => *', [

        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), {optional: true}),

        query(':enter', stagger('300ms', [
          animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
            style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0}),
            style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)',  offset: 0.3}),
            style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)',     offset: 1.0}),
          ]))]), {optional: true}),


          query(':leave', stagger('300ms', [
            animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
              style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 0}),
              style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)',  offset: 0.3}),
              style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)',     offset: 1.0}),
            ]))]), {optional: true})
      ])
    ])

 <div class="row"  [@listOfDivsInOut]="_customersDTO.CustomerList.length">
<div class="col-md-6"   *ngFor='let c of _customersDTO.CustomerList
| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: _currentpage, totalItems: _customersDTO.totalItems }'>
```

i'm paginate result in pages, when i go from page to other i need to excute enter animation after leave finished.